# Duplicate Column with same name is getting Creating when using Code First Approach (postgres)

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

I am using Code First approach for creating the database. My Database is in postgres as backend and i am using asp.net core for API development. I have modidifed my table as Following
Added Following column in the table structure

```
public virtual int? OEMarketplaceProviderId​ { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OEMarketplaceProviderId​​")]
    public virtual OEMarketPlaceProvider OEMarketplaceProviderId​FK { get; set; }
    public virtual string LongDescription​ { get; set; }
    public virtual int? OEEnumNotificationStatus​Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OEEnumNotificationStatus​Id​")]
    public OEEnumMaster OEEnumNotificationStatus​Fk { get; set; }

    // inplace of OESystemStatusMasterId
    public virtual int? Status { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Status​​")]
    public OEEnumMaster StatusFk { get; set; }
```

Migration Generated

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "OEEnumNotificationStatusId",
                table: "OESystem",
                nullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "OEEnumNotificationStatus​Id​",
                table: "OESystem",
                nullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "OEMarketplaceProviderId",
                table: "OESystem",
                nullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "OEMarketplaceProviderId​​",
                table: "OESystem",
                nullable: true);
 

 -
```

Snapshot Generated

```
b.HasOne("OneEnterprise.iHUB.OEEnumMasters.OEEnumMaster", "OEEnvironmentMasterFk")
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey("OEEnvironmentMasterId");

                    b.HasOne("OneEnterprise.iHUB.OEMarketPlaceProviders.OEMarketPlaceProvider", "OEMarketplaceProviderIdFK")
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey("OEMarketplaceProviderIdâ€‹â€‹");

                    b.HasOne("OneEnterprise.iHUB.OEEnumMasters.OEEnumMaster", "OESystemStatusMasterFk")
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey("OESystemStatusMasterId");

                    b.HasOne("OneEnterprise.iHUB.OEEnumMasters.OEEnumMaster", "StatusFk")
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey("Statusâ€‹â€‹");

                    b.HasOne("OneEnterprise.iHUB.SystemSpecification.SystemInfo", "SystemInfoFk")
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey("SystemInfoId");
```

Related Entity

```
[Required]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual string Code { get; set; }

        public virtual string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual string NameLanguageId { get; set; }

        public virtual string DescriptionLanguageId { get; set; }

        public virtual string ToolTip { get; set; }

        public virtual string ToolTipLanguageId { get; set; }

        public virtual string HelpId { get; set; }

        public virtual EnumType EnumType { get; set; }

        public virtual bool IsDefault { get; set; }
```

Entity 2

```
 public virtual string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual string Address { get; set; }

        public virtual string Phone { get; set; }

        public virtual string Mail { get; set; }

        public virtual string Website { get; set; }

        public virtual int OEBusinessPartnerId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OEBusinessPartnerId")]
        public OEBusinessPartner OEBusinessPartnerFk { get; set; }

        public virtual int? OEEnumMasterBusinessPartnerStatusId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OEEnumMasterBusinessPartnerStatusId")]
        public OEEnumMaster OEEnumMasterBusinessPartnerStatusFk { get; set; }

        public virtual int? OEMarketPlaceOfferId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OEMarketPlaceOfferId")]
        public OEMarketPlaceOffer OEMarketPlaceOfferFk { get; set; }

        public virtual int? OEMarketPlaceRatingId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OEMarketPlaceRatingId")]
        public OEMarketPlaceRating OEMarketPlaceRatingFk { get; set; }
```

Please suggest what could be the reason and if is Deployed in the Testing environment. How we can fix it.
In Snapshot we can easily check that duplicate column has been created in Migration and snapshot, however in entity i have placed the column name only once

thanks
Ashish

Comment: You have to show all related classes, not just this one.

Comment: when i Debugged the Code i found the following structure of the Table 
      OEEnumNotificationStatusId (Nullable<int>)
      OEEnumNotificationStatus​Id​ (no field, Nullable<int>) Shadow FK Index

Comment: what  is this  (no field, Nullable<int>) Shadow FK Index